# Weak star closure and Eberlein-Smulian theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the implication $(iii)\rightarrow(i)$ on Albiac and Kalton's proof of the Eberlein-Smulian Theorem. Specifically, why $x^{\ast\ast}\in \overline{A_0}^{w^\ast}$. I thought of showing that $$\overline{A_0}^{w^\ast} = \{y^{\ast\ast}\in X^{\ast\ast} : y^{\ast\ast}(x^\ast) \geq 1\}$$ but while the inclusion $\subset$ is immediate, to show the other one, given $y^{\ast\ast}$ such that $y^{\ast\ast}(x^\ast) \geq 1$, I tried to construct a net in $A_0$ converging to $y^{\ast\ast}$. Not only could I not make such construction but also it seems that it would be the same as constructing such a net converging to $x^{\ast\ast}$ and showing directly that $x^{\ast\ast}\in \overline{A_0}^{w^\ast}$.

Instead of constructing a net, I also tried to find a convenient neighborhood basis for the weak* topology to work with and show that for every weak* neighborhood $V$ of $x^{\ast\ast}$, $V\cap A_0\neq\emptyset$, but all to no avail. I'd appreciate some suggestions on how to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be a weak$^*$-open neighborhood of $x^{**}$, and put $V_0=\{y^{**}\in X^{**}:y^{**}(x^{*})>1\}$.  Then $V\cap V_0$ is a weak$^*$-open neighborhood of $x^{**}$, hence it contains some $x\in A$.  Since $x\in A\cap V_0$, we know $x\in A_0$ (since $A_0$ is, by definition, $A\cap V_0$).  Thus $A\cap V_0\cap V= A_0\cap V$ is nonempty, so $x^{**}$ is in the weak$^*$-closure of $A_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $J$ be the canonical embedding of $X$ on $X^{\ast\ast}$. Notice that $x^{\ast\ast}\in \overline{J(A)}^{w^\ast}$, which means that for all neighbourhood $x^{\ast\ast}\in V \Rightarrow V\cap J(A)\neq\emptyset$. Now, consider the open set $\tilde{A}=\{y\in X^{\ast\ast} | y(x^\ast)>1\}$, for which it is clear that $J(A_0)\subset \tilde{A}$, furthermore $x^{\ast\ast}\in \tilde{A}$. Hence for each neighbourhood $V$ of $x^{\ast\ast}$, $V\cap\tilde{A}$ is also a neighbourhood of $x^{\ast\ast}$, then $V\cap\tilde{A}\cap J(A) \neq \emptyset$, but $\tilde{A}\cap J(A)=A_0$.